# iPhone and iPad projects separated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I’’ve been developing an iPhone app in swift 4 and I’m about to start a new version for iPad too

My client has specially requested that the app’s GUI is built in code and not using storyboard, so I was wondering what’s the best approach in this case. Adaptive layout works well when working with storyboard, also gui designs are way too different for both versions, it’s not just a matter of resizing

Please any suggestions ?

Comment: Code that constructs interface differently depending whether this is an iPhone or an iPad? `if` is your friend. Hard to tell what else you could be wondering about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get `UIScreen.current.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom`. It will be `.phone` or `.pad`. Use `if` to proceed accordingly with the construction of the interface.

Comment: Up-voted. This is basically what I do. Since it's easier to embed a "regular" view controller in a "navigation" view controller from the story board, I found the info.plist option to do separate storyboards, and then use `UIDevice.current.model.range(of: "iPad") != nil` in `AppDelegate` for the rest. @matt, what's the difference between `UIDevice` and `UIScreen`? Are they basically the same?

Comment: @dfd Definitely could use UIDevice instead. — Note that if we _were_ allowed to use storyboards / nibs, there is a totally automatic way to load one on iPhone and another on iPad. But the OP said that that was forbidden so I didn't mention it.

Comment: thank you guys for your quick response, I think I'll go ahead and use UIScreen to decide which code to execute.